# how to access an array inside structure using a structure pointer

Tags: c, pointers, structure

```
struct node{
    char a[100];
    struct node* next;
};
typedef struct node* nodeptr;
main()
{
    char b[100];
    nodeptr p;  
    int n;          
    printf("enter the string\n");
    scanf("%s",b);          
    n=strlen(b);                
    p=getnode();                    
    p->a=b;                             
    p->next=null;                           
    printf("%s \n",(q->a));                     
    return 0;                                       
}
```

How can I access the array inside the struct using a struct pointer? Is this the correct method? I am getting the following error during compilation:

`incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[100]’ from type ‘char *’ "`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code at `p->a=b` is simply not allowed as a is an array and not a pointer and you are trying to copy a pointer to an array. Try `strncpy(p->a, b, 100)` (of course you should have 100 as a `#define`)

Comment: Actually I was wrong, my suggestion is still correct, but the reason is wrong, I corrected my answer. And I recommend strncpy instead of a for loop because you want to put a string into it.

Answer (score 4):

Arrays can not be copied in C.

You are accessing them correctly but you need to copy the array value by value.

Change

```
p->a=b;
```

Into

```
for(int loop=0;loop < 100;++loop)
{
    p->a[loop] = b[loop];
}
```

Comment: +1 because your example is illustrative, despite not the most efficient way (readability-wise) to do it.